# Show Folders in IOS created by Unity App

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, directory

How can i show folders in iOS created by an App?

I builded a personal app in iOS that create some folder in Documents folder.

Which external app i have to use to show these folders?

Comment: One thing, use **Application.persistentDataPath** and nothing else.

Comment: If you want to know where that is on a Mac, google *"unity3d where is Application.persistentDataPath on a Mac?"* to get the answer instantly